# Strange artifacts in triangle low poly mesh

Tags: mesh

here's the problem I have. I triangulated my mesh for better low poly look, extruded some faces to have a little hill and got pretty bad result. My mesh when render has some strange artifacts and I cant figure out why. Can somebody help?[image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/